# How to compile C and C++ files together in eclipse?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, compiler-errors, android-ndk

I have a source code containing .c files which is built using ndk build in eclipse Ide. I want to add a .cpp file , in which i need to import my .c files. I get compile time issues when I do the same. Most of the issues are due to type casting to user defined data types. The compilation runs fine, and ndk -build is successful with only .c files

```
jni/folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\src\abc.c:963:29: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'MY_STATUS_CODE' [-fpermissive]
```

How can I solve this?!

Comment: "I want to add a .cpp file , in which i need to import my .c files" That does not make any sense. The .c files contain C code, right? If you include a file in a .cpp file which you compile with a C++ compiler, it will be compiled as if it was written in C++ which is likely to fail. I doubt that you really need to include those files. It's generally very bad design to include source files in another.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But I am trying to use google test which happens to be a test framework written in c++. And it can be used to test c code as well ...as long as c++ compiler can compile c source files

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with google's test framework but I find it odd that it's use would require one to include a source file in another. Some C++ compilers certainly can compile C source files, but they can't compile C code that's inside a C++ source file. Unless the C code happens to also be valid C++ code. Judging by your error, this is not the case with your C code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't include C code in a C++ source file unless the C code is valid C++. The compilation error shows that your C code is not valid C++.

You could try to work around the problem by changing your C code to be also valid C++ but that's a waste of time in my opinion. The proper way to solve the error is to not include the C source file but compile it separately. Including a source file in another is bad design anyway so you'll get rid of that smell for free.